# Mutable version of Map.merge

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8

Java 8 has introduced some nice methods to the `Map` interface. To me, a gap is that there is no mutable version of the `merge` method.

For example, suppose `map` is a `Map<String, List<Integer>>` and you want to do this:

```
List<Integer> list = map.get("a");
if (list == null)
    list = map.put("a", new ArrayList<>());
list.add(1);
```

(I am aware that you can use Guava's `MultiMap` for this kind of thing, but I am interested in standard Java.)

To me, it feels like there ought to be a nice way of simplifying this in Java 8, but I can't find it. I reckon it should be a single method call, like

```
map.mutableMerge("a", 1, ArrayList::new, List::add);     // Not real code
```

but the best I could come up with using the new methods is

```
map.computeIfAbsent("a", k -> new ArrayList<>());
map.compute("a", (k, v) -> {
    v.add(1);
    return v;
});
```

but this is no better than the original. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) returns the value associated with the key, which is either the current one or the one constructed by the mapping function. So you can simply have

```
map.computeIfAbsent("a", k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(1);
```

Comment: I knew they must have thought of it and that I was just being thick, I'll accept in 15 minutes. Thank you.